# Require 2gb of RAM iOS App

Tags: ios

Is there a way to require a certain amount of RAM on an iOS app?

For example: if my app needed 2gb of RAM to run, how would I specify that? Note: my app does not require this much memory, this figure is just for the sake of the question.

I was thinking that this could be accomplished through the "Required device capabilities" in the Info.plist, but there is no such attribute listed in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3

Any ideas?

Comment: Apple won't let you require something like this as far as I know.  I believe there is a way to specify what devices your app officially supports, however.

Comment: @nhgrif: how would I do that?

Comment: Old School: Read the Apple docs.

Comment: @zaph: which Apple docs are you referring to?

Comment: Actually learning what docs are available and what they cover is even  more important. You find that out by reading lot's of docs at least partially.

Comment: @zaph: I have read many Apple docs, and do know what they cover, however, I have not found the answer to my question in the docs I have perused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and in a multitasking environment is no way to hog all memory from the system. You app will simply get terminated during runtime.

The correct approach is to determine during runtime how much ram you could get and scale the requirements down. If you absolutely need 2gb ram then it is more likely that you need a redesign.

Comment: Ah, hog as much memory as possible.